# QT Quick, content drawn below caption/title bar on windows?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

As of lately my content of my window is shifted up so that its drawn below my caption bar, its weird and its either a bug or I'm missing something basic, any pointers would be appreciated:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle{
        width: 100
        x: 0
        y: 0
        height: 35
        color: "#888888"
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

one would expect a rectangle below the caption bar, but I get a rect which is partly hidden by the caption: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCbSq.png

I'm on Windows 10, msvcs2013/2015, qt 5.8, 32/64 bit

Can you reproduce this behaviour and/or do you have a solution so that the rectangle is drawn below the caption like one expects?

Comment: I tried the code that shows and works well in Linux, maybe in windows the position `x = 0`, `y = 0` does not start after the caption bar, but from before, I recommend changing `y = 0` to `y = 10` or more.

Comment: The solution has to work on mobile devices as well, thus a shift is not my way to go (as long as i can't use ifdefs in qml but thats a different story)

if you do the following instead of x/y/width/height it yields the same result.        height: 35 /            anchors.right: parent.right /       anchors.left: parent.left /            anchors.top: parent.top

Comment: What I wanted to say in my comment is that the problem you have is a Qt bug for mobile, so I would recommend you to report it, the idea I proposed was only to temporarily mitigate this error since the code you show is simple and not I think it's a programming error from you.

Comment: Thats definitly a bug. File a bugreport at https://bugreports.qt.io

Comment: done, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made a bug report, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62922 hopefully it will be solved someday

since i intended a fullscreen app anyway i use:

```
visibility: "Maximized"    // does not hide the windows taskbar
//visibility: "FullScreen" // does     hide the windows taskbar
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.Window // frameless, but with an icon on the windows taskbar
```

**EDIT:**

**Seems to be related to an intel driver**, do not use version *.4664, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62127 as well